# (Python) How can I convert a list of integers into a list of sets where each set is a pair of these integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I have a list `E = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and I will like to convert it into `E = [{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}]` in the least computationally expensive manner. In particular, I will like to extend this to large instances of `E`.

Is there an efficient way to do this in Python (3.5 & later)?

Remark: `E` will always be given as an even-sized list, as I am working on graphs related topics

Comment: Is the list always going to be an even number of elements?

Comment: @JGreenwell Yes it is. I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the best method would be using `iter`+`zip` in a list comprehension

```
s = iter(E)
[{a,b} for a,b in zip(s,s)]
```

Explanation: `zip(s,s)` performs a pretty efficient pairwise grouping of `E` if `s` is its `iter`.

Comment: Only if the list is evenly sized.

Comment: @coldspeed thanks for the comment! If not evenly sized, have to add manually the last item

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I tried it on large instances of E (in the thousands), and it runs pretty fast :)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over a rolling slice of 2 of `E`:

```
[set(E[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(E), 2)]
```

Note that this works for odd-sized lists as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll accept @RafaelC's answer as it runs somewhat faster than your implementation. P.S. Ran out of up votes for the day, somehow :/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `zip()` plus slicing:

```
[{x, y} for x, y in zip(E[::2], E[1::2])]
```